Dexing error when integrating aar file into Flutter app
I have a calcapp.aar file that I want to use in a Flutter app. I created the libs folder inside android/app and added the calcapp.aar file to it -> android/app/libs/calcapp.aar. Then, I added the following code to android/app/build.gradle:
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'calcapp', ext: 'aar')
}

After that, I ran the project, and the following error occurred:
The error screenshot
Folder structure screenshot
build.gradle screenshot
I tried the following commands:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
However, the result did not change.
My current setup is:
Flutter version: 3.22.2
Dart version: 3.4.3
Gradle version: 7.6.3
I know that to use the calcapp.aar functions and methods in Flutter, I must use MethodChannel. However, my main problem currently is that after adding this dependency to the project, the project does not run (I just want it to run before configuring MethodChannel).

Is there a reason you are using an .aar and not a .jar file?

No, because the Gomobile tool exports my Go code for Android as an AAR file. @tomerpacific

Once this issue is fixed, you only need to change the Gradle version in android/settings.gradle within the plugins statement and update the value of com.android.application to 8.1.1:
plugins {
    ....
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    ...
}

Additionally, update the value in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties for distributionUrl to 8.1:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-all.zip

